# Aplicación shiny no funciona

Tags: r

Estoy tratando de probar shiny con un ejemplo, al que no le encuentro el error, al ejecutarlo me aparece en el browser el siguiente error: **ERROR: unable to start png() device**. Alguien puede decirme que debo corregir del siguiente código???:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
datasets <- data(package = "ggplot2")$results[, "Item"]
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("dataset", "Dataset", choices = datasets),
  verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
  tableOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dataset2 <- reactive({
    get(input$dataset, "package:ggplot2")
  })
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(dataset2())
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(dataset2())
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunos temas en tu aplicación:

1. Estas haciendo un `tableOutput()` cuando en realidad quieres dibujar un `plot`, en todo caso entiendo que deberías definir algo así: `plotOutput("plot")`
2. El otro problema es que no puedes simplemente hacer un `plot` sobre el `data.frame` seleccionado así como así, cada uno tiene sus características, sus variables. A modo de ejemplo podrías intentar obtener las dos primeras columnas de cada base de datos y tratar que `plot()` las trate como un gráfico de puntos común

Finalmente tu código:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

datasets <- data(package = "ggplot2")$results[, "Item"]
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("dataset", "Dataset", choices = datasets),
  verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
  plotOutput("plot")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dataset2 <- reactive({
    get(input$dataset, "package:ggplot2")
  })
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(dataset2())
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(dataset2()[, c(1,2)])
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Gracias por responder Patricio :).  El código que publiqué responde a un ejercicio (5) de: mastering-shiny.org/basic-app.html#exercises. Pero hasta donde leí no explicaron lo que me comentas. Yo encontré sólo 2 errores y no el 3ro :(